# regex for replacing only double apostrophes

Tags: regex, vb.net, str-replace

I already searched SO and I could not find an answer.

I need to replace all non-double apostrophes with a single apostrophe.

```
abc'def''ghi'x -> abc''def''hgi''x

''abc'def' -> ''abc''def''

'abc''def -> ''abc''def
```

I dont want this:

```
abc''def -> abc''''def
```

All of the solutions I've seen fail if the apostrophe is at the start or at the end. I use vbnet. Any help welcome. Regex or some other form of code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple regex is `(?<!')'(?!')`